# PyQt4 GUI to run terminal commands

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, pyqt4

I'm new to PyQt4 and I have 2 questions.

1. I want to create a GUI by which for example when I press a button, a terminal command run (e.g. `ping www.google.com`)
2. can I import cvlc in part of GUI

to wrap up I want to create a GUI in which when I press a button

```
cvlc  -v v4l2:///dev/video0
```

runs and the cvlc window is shown in the GUI.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could run the commands with the OS library. With `os.system("ping www.google.com")`. Im not sure on how you want the output to display, are you trying to get what is printed in the terminal so you can display it in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve first part i.e. when ping button is pressed it pings google.com and the output is displayed on a terminal.

```
import sys,os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 150,150)
        self.ping = QPushButton('Press to ping', self)
        self.ping.move(10,20)
        self.ping.clicked.connect(self.gotoPing)

    def gotoPing(self):
        os.system("ping www.google.com")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```